# Insert data in room database using data class object

Tags: android, android-room

- How can I insert data in Room database using data class? I tried inserting but it fails with -1 as response in the response ?
- How to get error message when something fails in `Room Database`?

Code:

```
 @Insert(onConflict = OnConflictStrategy.IGNORE)
 fun insertData(dataclass: DataClass): Long
```

Insertion:

```
var result = dao.insertData(DataClass(id=1,name="Hello")) //result is -1
```

Answer (score 1):

Code:

```
@Dao
public interface DaoName{
      @Insert
         public void insertData(DataClass dataclass);
}
```

Insertion:(Put this code in a Thread)

```
 MyDatabase db = MyDatabase.getInstance(Context);
 DataClass dataClass = new DataClass();
 dataClass.id = 1
 DataClass.name = "Hello"
 db.DaoName().insertData(dataClass);
```

Comment: The user's code is Kotlin.  Your answer is Java.  It would be better to provide an answer written in Kotlin.

Answer (score 1):

I usually access it from local data source class and use it in view model
(I use Hilt for dependency injection)

Entity class:

```
@Entity(tableName = PROGRESS_BOOK_TABLE)
class ProgressBookEntity(
    var progressBook: AllProgressBookEntry
) {
    @PrimaryKey(autoGenerate = false)
    var id: Int = 0
}
```

Dao

```
@Dao
interface ProgressBookDao {
    @Insert(onConflict = OnConflictStrategy.REPLACE)
    fun insertProgressBook(progressBookEntity: ProgressBookEntity)
}
```

Local Data Source

```
class LocalDataSource @Inject constructor(
    private val progressBookDao: ProgressBookDao
) {
    suspend fun insertProgressBook(progressBookEntity: ProgressBookEntity) {
        progressBookDao.insertProgressBook(progressBookEntity)
    }
}
```

From related view model class:

```
private fun insertProgressBook(progressBookEntity: ProgressBookEntity) {
        viewModelScope.launch(Dispatchers.IO) {
            repository.local.insertProgressBook(progressBookEntity)
        }
    }
```

And call the function in a fragment or activity file and pass the value of your preferred data class type.